# Node.JS Firebase Cloud Function - HTTP Request - Return JSON response to client

Tags: node.js, json, request, google-cloud-functions

I am writing a firebase cloud function to connect to an external database upon HTTP trigger.

This function will do the following:

1. User submits account number and zipcode
2. Cloud function is triggered
3. Account number is appended to URL in request and the external database returns account number and zipcode.

I need to return the response body back to the client.

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
var request = require('request');

exports.account_verification = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    console.log("Data: " + data.text);
    console.log("Context: " + context)

    var options = {
        'method': 'GET',
        'url': '**REDACTED**' + JSON.parse(data.text).customerno,
        'headers': {
        }
    };


     request(options, function (error, response) {
        if (error) throw new Error(error);
        console.log("RESPONSE BODY: ", JSON.parse(response.body).firebase_accounts);
        console.log("Data Submitted: ", data.text);
        console.log("Account Submitted: ", JSON.parse(data.text).customerno);
        console.log("Zip Submitted: ", JSON.parse(data.text).zipcode);

        //data returned from external database
        //Example: firebase_accounts:[{"customerno" : "Example Customer", "zipcode" : "Example Zip Code"}]


        var response_returned = JSON.parse(response.body).firebase_accounts;
         console.log("Data Returned -- Parsed: ", response_returned);
        //Example: [{"customerno" : "Example Customer", "zipcode": "Example Zip Code"}]

 //Response Body available here but will not return to client

    });

//Return to client will work here but cannot access response data

});
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code you shared? When you run it in Cloud Functions, or in the [emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_functions), what line doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: I am running it within cloud functions, not the cloud emulator for the time being. I am trying to return the "response returned" back to the client in JSON format. 

//data returned from external database
        var response_returned = JSON.parse(response.body).firebase_accounts;
         console.log("Data Returned -- Parsed: ", response_returned);
    
    });
//return works here but the response body is unavailable to return
});

Comment: Please edit your question to include the additional information, so that you can use the formatting tools to make it more readable.

Comment: Frank, Thank You for taking the time to review my post; I have edited the question in hopes to bring more clarification to the question at hand. Best Regards, -Arcade336

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're performing an asynchronous request, you'll need to make sure that Cloud Functions waits for that result. This is sometimes referred to as bubbling up the result.

It's easiest when you use promises, but since you're using the `request` module, that isn't available in there. Instead you can create your own promise, like this:

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
var request = require('request');

exports.account_verification = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    var options = {
        'method': 'GET',
        'url': '**REDACTED**' + JSON.parse(data.text).customerno,
        'headers': {
        }
    };

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      request(options, function (error, response) {
        if (error) reject(error);

        var response_returned = JSON.parse(response.body).firebase_accounts;

        resolve(response_returned);
      });
    })
});
```

Comment: Frank, It worked! Thank You for taking the time on my question. It had me stumped for a while. I really do appreciate your assistance on this. Best Regards, -Arcade336